# Which road groupset should I choose?

Tags: road-bike, groupsets

I am planning to buy a used road bike, so i have two options of gropsets (front/rear derailleur + shifters):

1. newer Shimano Tiagra (bianchi impulso 2016-2017?) (pic 1-2)
2. campagnolo veloce, i dont know which year is this model (Bianchi Nirone 7) (pic 3)

As i understand, veloce is kind of higher level (but is is true for newer tiagra?), and shimano is easier and cheaper to maintain. Any thoughts on that? thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In these C19 times, its more a question of what can you get, and selecting from those options.

Answer (score 3):

Most groupset comparisons place Campagnolo Veloce on the same level as the Shimano Tiagra or Shimano 105 groupsets.

So from quality and performance/weight point of view they should be relatively comparable. If they are both the latest generation they also both come with 2x10 speeds.

Instead I’d focus on three different aspects:

- Wear. You say the Veloce is used. How much? Does it need a new chain, new cables, new cassette? At least the cable housing going to the rear derailleur looks like it should be replaced (kink where it goes into the derailleur).
- Gear ratio. Campagnolo tends to have gears which are totally not suitable for hilly (or mountainous) terrain. Their 10s cassette with the biggest sprocket is 13–29 and the rear derailleur only works with up to 30 teeth (compared to 11–34 on the Tiagra). What does the bike come with? A 12–25t cassette and a 52/39t crankset would set the “minimum” speed at 15km/h for a 75rpm cadence.
- Ergonomics. Do you like the Campagnolo or Shimano shifters more?

Comment: Shimano is also used, but it looks like it has a better condition (i've updated the pics). Im not sure about Compagnolo generation , but judging by the bike model it is defenetly 9-10 years old. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

What Michael says. And also: how much money are you saving by buying used? A new 105 or Tiagra set is not that expensive (but ymmv) and on a new set, you have more options.